# Is there any artistic representation of Mawhrin-Skel?

Tags: iain-m-banks, the-culture

I'm currently reading "[The Player of Games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Player_of_Games)" from [Iain M. Banks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iain_M._Banks)'s [Culture Cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Culture).

I'm having difficulty picturing the character of Mawhrin-Skel Drone (and [Drones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Culture#Drones) in general since they "*are floating units of varying size and **shape***"). I was wondering if there is any artistic representation of him somewhere on the web?

Comment: Those coloured force fields… It's one of these things that really should exist (there ought to be a rule), but I had no luck with easily-available covers or fanart.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[DeviantArt](http://www.deviantart.com/) can be a good source for conceptualizations.....
I could not find a Mawhrin-Skel but these might help give you a visual:

[Unaha-Closp drone from Consider Phlebas](http://verox11.deviantart.com/art/Unaha-Closp-Culture-Drone-135187558/)

[Djan Seriy Anaplian and Turminder-Xuss from Matter](http://lostro.deviantart.com/art/Djan-Seriy-Anaplian-130411578/)

Comment: Good source, by searching "Culture Drone" I fond [this particularly good conceptualization of the force fields](http://mrtake.deviantart.com/art/Culture-Drone-35160023?q=boost%3Apopular%20Culture%20Drone&qo=1)

Answer (score 9):

[*Something Real*](http://www.jonrennie.co.uk/films/79-something-real.html) (also on [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ET8IFxPo61w)) is a short film directed by [Jon Rennie](http://www.jonrennie.co.uk/) set in the Culture universe. The drone is different, but hopefully it gives you some idea of what they are like.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't found any art that matches what I see when reading the books.  Banks almost always describes drones in the same way: metallic oblongs devoid of features or ornamentation.  Function over form.

In *Excession* he describes a drone's "suitcase-sized body."  This seems to be the prevailing appearance throughout the series.  "People always said drones looked a bit like suitcases but this one reminded Genar-Hofoen of an old-fashioned sledge," he says later in the same book.

In *Consider Phlebas*:  "It was the size and shape of a standard suit backpack."

In *Use of Weapons*: "The drone was the size - and near enough the shape - of a small suitcase."

In *The Hydrogen Sonata*: "The drone ... was the size and shape of a large grey suitcase ... rather battered and dusty ... its scraped, slightly dented casing glinted in the sunlight..."

In *Surface Detail*: "A drone like a small smooth suitcase floated near the woman's shoulder."

In *Matter*: "The machine looked like a scruffy metal suitcase."

A different design is described in *Look to Windward*: "The machine was a little less than a metre in height, and half that in width and depth.  Its rounded-off rectangular casing was made of delicate pink porcelain held in a lattice of gently glowing blue lumenstone.  Beyond the porcelain's translucent surface, the drone's internal components could just be made out; shadows beneath its thin ceramic skin.  Its aura field, confined to a small volume directly underneath its flat basse, was a soft blush of magenta..."  This appears to be the exception.

Everything I've seen online is perhaps more interesting but not accurate.